Passing the limit through convergence
Suppose we have random variables $\{X_{n,m},n,m\geq1\}$. For each $m$, we know there exists a random variable $X_m$ such that $X_{n,m}$ converges in distribution to $X_m$ as $n\to\infty$. Moreover, we know that $X_m$ converges almost surely to a constant $c$.
Would it be possible that $X_{n,m}$ converges to $c$ in some sense?
I once read a ''close'' conclusion in Billingsley's book, Theorem 5.5. But it seems that I can not use the proving method there to show some convergence of the setting I am thinking ):
Thanks ahead for any guidance!

This depends on how $m,n\to \infty$.
Suppose
$$
X_{n,m}=\begin{cases}
m & \text{if }n\le m;\\
\pm m& \text{with equal probabilities $\frac1n$ if }n> m;\\
 0& \text{with probability $1-\frac2n$ if }n> m.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $X_{n,m}\to 0=:X_m$ as $n\to \infty$ in probability and in distribution. And obviously $X_m\to 0$. But $X_{m,m}=m$ converges to infinity.

Many thanks for your reply! Are you aware of any related/similar results that describe this kind of "passing convergence"?

@PercyW, unfortunately not, I just "cooked" this example for you problem. It reminds somehow Cantor's diagonal argument: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument
